# MySQL time fields, checking boundaries/inclusion

Tags: mysql

I have two columns of type time, 24 hours. They define a range of when someone is available. Example:

```
10:00:00    14:30:00
```

Is there an easy way to do a query that asks if the current time is between those two columns? Apologies if this is basic, couldn't find an easy way to do it while browsing the MySQL time/date functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. I'd have to test it to be certain.

```
SELECT * FROM `available_table` WHERE ( TIME(NOW()) > `begin_time` AND TIME(NOW()) < `end_time` )
```

Answer (score 1):

The other suggestions will work, but I recommend using the `BETWEEN` keyword which is meant for this stuff.

```
WHERE DateTime BETWEEN TIME(Start_Time) AND TIME(End_Time)
```

That will get everything within that range.

[Documentation for BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between).

Comment: The boundaries for `BETWEEN` are variables here though.

Comment: Good call. This should work better than my answer, when you take midnight into account.  But if he's just comparing times (and his columns are TIME types), shouldn't you wrap your date expressions in TIME()?

Comment: @Jonathon: THanks, didn't notice that.. tell me if this is what you were saying

Comment: Should be a combination of the 2: `WHERE TIME(NOW()) BETWEEN STARTTIME AND ENDTIME`.  However that is exactly equivalent to MySQL with what Jonathon proposed.